# Defining a UDF that accepts an Array of objects in a Spark DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

When working with Spark's DataFrames, User Defined Functions (UDFs) are required for mapping data in columns. UDFs require that argument types are explicitly specified. In my case, I need to manipulate a column that is made up of arrays of objects, and I do not know what type to use. Here's an example:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._

// Start with some data. Each row (here, there's only one row) 
// is a topic and a bunch of subjects
val data = sqlContext.read.json(sc.parallelize(Seq(
  """
  |{
  |  "topic" : "pets",
  |  "subjects" : [
  |    {"type" : "cat", "score" : 10},
  |    {"type" : "dog", "score" : 1}
  |  ]
  |}
  """)))
```

It's relatively straightforward to use the built-in `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` to perform basic operations on the data in the columns

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.size
data.select($"topic", size($"subjects")).show

+-----+--------------+
|topic|size(subjects)|
+-----+--------------+
| pets|             2|
+-----+--------------+
```

and it's generally easy to write custom UDFs to perform arbitrary operations

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val enhance = udf { topic : String => topic.toUpperCase() }
data.select(enhance($"topic"), size($"subjects")).show 

+----------+--------------+
|UDF(topic)|size(subjects)|
+----------+--------------+
|      PETS|             2|
+----------+--------------+
```

But what if I want to use a UDF to manipulate the array of objects in the "subjects" column? What type do I use for the argument in the UDF? For example, if I want to reimplement the size function, instead of using the one provided by spark:

```
val my_size = udf { subjects: Array[Something] => subjects.size }
data.select($"topic", my_size($"subjects")).show
```

Clearly `Array[Something]` does not work... what type should I use!? Should I ditch `Array[]` altogether? Poking around tells me `scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray` may have something to do with it, but still there's another type I need to provide.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What you're looking for is `Seq[o.a.s.sql.Row]`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val my_size = udf { subjects: Seq[Row] => subjects.size }
```

**Explanation**:

- Current representation of `ArrayType` is, as you already know, `WrappedArray` so `Array` won't work and it is better to stay on the safe side.
- [According to the official specification](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types), the local (external) type for `StructType` is `Row`. Unfortunately it means that access to the individual fields is not type safe.

**Notes**:

- To create `struct` in Spark < 2.3, function passed to `udf` has to return `Product` type (`Tuple*` or `case class`), not `Row`. That's because corresponding `udf` variants [depend on Scala reflection](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$):

  > Defines a Scala closure of *n* arguments as user-defined function (UDF). The data types are automatically inferred based on the Scala closure's signature.
- In Spark >= 2.3 it is possible to return `Row` directly, [as long as the schema is provided](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@udf(f:AnyRef,dataType:org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType):org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction).

  > `def udf(f: AnyRef, dataType: DataType): UserDefinedFunction`
  >   Defines a deterministic user-defined function (UDF) using a Scala closure. For this variant, the caller must specify the output data type, and there is no automatic input type coercion.

  See for example [How to create a Spark UDF in Java / Kotlin which returns a complex type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50949384).