# UDF to Concatenate Arrays of Undefined Case Class Buried in a Row Object

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe, called sessions, with columns that may change over time. (**Edit to Clarify**: I do not have a case class for the columns - only a reflected schema.) I will consistently have a uuid and clientId in the outer scope with some other inner and outer scope columns that might constitute a tracking event so ... something like:

```
root
 |-- runtimestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |-- clientId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- uuid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- oldTrackingEvents: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- actionid: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- actiontype: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- <tbd ... maps, arrays and other stuff matches sibling> section
 ...
 |-- newTrackingEvents: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- actionid: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- actiontype: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- <tbd ... maps, arrays and other stuff matches sibling>      
 ...
```

I'd like to now merge oldTrackingEvents and newTrackingEvents with a UDF containing these parameters and yet-to-be resolved code logic:

```
val mergeTEs = udf((oldTEs : Seq[Row], newTEs :  Seq[Row]) =>
        // do some stuff - figure best way 
        //    - to merge both groups of tracking events
        //    - remove duplicates tracker events structures
        //    - limit total tracking events < 500 
        return result // same type as UDF input params
    )
```

The UDF return result would be an array of of the structure that is the resulting List of the concatenated two fields.

**QUESTION:**
My question is how to construct such a UDF - (1) use of correct passed-in parameter types, (2) a way to manipulate these collections within a UDF and (3) a clear way to return a value that doesn't have a compiler error. I unsuccessfully tested `Seq[Row]` for the input / output (with `val testUDF = udf((trackingEvents : Seq[Row]) => trackingEvents)` and received the error `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Row is not supported` for a direct return of `trackingEvents`. However, I get no error for returning `Some(1)` instead of `trackingEvents` ... What is the best way to manipulate the collections so that I can concatenate 2 lists of identical structures as suggested by the schema above with the UDF using the activity in the comments section. The goal is to use this operation:

```
sessions.select(mergeTEs('oldTrackingEvents, 'newTrackingEvents).as("cleanTrackingEvents"))
```

And in each row, ... get back a single array of 'trackingEvents' structure in a memory / speed efficient manner.

**SUPPLEMENTAL:**

Looking at a question shown to me ... There's a possible hint, if relevancy exists ...  [Defining a UDF that accepts an Array of objects in a Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39006349/defining-a-udf-that-accepts-an-array-of-objects-in-a-spark-dataframe) ... `To create struct function passed to udf has to return Product type (Tuple* or case class), not Row.` 
Perhaps ... this other post is relevant / useful.

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to concatenate two columns each of Seq[Elem] to one column of Seq[Elem] in new column with the select statement alone?

Comment: Yes. There are lists, maps and structures within the 'trackingEvents' (array of 'trackingEvent') column  ... These can change so I cannot hard code a case class either.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the [question you've linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39006349/defining-a-udf-that-accepts-an-array-of-objects-in-a-spark-dataframe) explains it all, so just to reiterate. When working with `udf`:

- Input representation for the `StructType` is weakly typed `Row` object.
- Output type for `StructType` has to be Scala `Product`. You cannot return `Row` object.

If this is to much burden, you should use strongly typed `Dataset`

```
val f: T => U 
sessions.as[T].map(f): Dataset[U]
```

where `T` is an algebraic data type representing `Session` schema, and `U` is algebraic data type representing the result.

Comment: I'm starting to understand what you're implying. I think the issue is that I don't have `algebraic data type` ... I only have a schema inferred by `sessions.select('oldTrackingEvents).schema` (as this is the flexible type) and I am thinking this schema needs to be converted to a scala.product. BTW - I am also forced to use Spark 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternatively** ... If your goal is to merge sequences of some random row structure / schema with some manipulation, this is an alternative generally-stated approach that avoids the partitioning talk:

From the master dataframe, create dataframes for each trackingEvents section, `new` and `old`. With each, select the exploded 'trackingEvents' section's columns. Save these `val` dataframe declarations as `newTE` and `oldTE`.

Create another dataframe, where columns that are picked are unique to each tracking event in the arrays of `oldTrackingEvents` and `newTrackingEvents` such as each's `uuid`, `clientId` and event `timestamp`. Your pseudo-schema would be:

`(uuid: String, clientId : Long, newTE : Seq[Long], oldTE : Seq[Long])`

Use a UDF to join the two simple sequences of your structure, both `Seq[Long]` which is 'something like the untested' example:

```
val limitEventsUDF = udf { (newTE: Seq[Long], oldTE: Seq[Long], limit: Int, tooOld: Long) => {
    (newTE ++ oldTE).filter(_ > tooOld).sortWith(_ > _).distinct.take(limit) 
}}
```

The UDF will return a dataframe of cleaned tracking events  & you now have a very slim dataframe with removed events to self-join back to your exploded `newTE` and `oldTE` frames after being unioned back to each other.

GroupBy as needed thereafter using collect_list.

Still ... this seems like a lot of work - Should this be voted for this as `"the answer"` - I'm not sure?