# spark udf return same element throws error for array of struct

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-2.1

My spark version is 2.1.0. I'm just doing a dummy operation on a array i.e just returning back it with the below udf definition. But, it doesn't work!/

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").load("trans.txt").toDF("id", "dt", "amt")
val df2 = df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list(struct('dt,'amt)).as("trans_vec"))
df2.show(false)
df2.printSchema()

def gen_rows(x:Seq[(String,String)]):Seq[(String,String)]={
  x
}
val udf_gen_rows = udf( gen_rows(_:Seq[(String,String)]):Seq[(String,String)] )

df2.withColumn("row_number",udf_gen_rows('trans_vec)).show(false)
```

It throws the below error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'UDF(trans_vec)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires array<struct<_1:string,_2:string>> type, however, '`trans_vec`' is of array<struct<dt:string,amt:string>> type.;;
```

How to fix this?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining a UDF that accepts an Array of objects in a Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39006349/defining-a-udf-that-accepts-an-array-of-objects-in-a-spark-dataframe)

Comment: someone posted an answer and before I could work on it.. it was deleted..

Comment: I posted one, but decided it doesn't really make sense to keep it, as you won't be able to use it for anything else than naive identity. To reiterate - this `udf_gen_rows('trans_vec).cast("array<struct<_1: string, _2: string>>")` would pass, but has not practical applications

Comment: ok.. actually I wanted to add a sequence number (String,String,Int) and return it in the UDF, but it was throwing error.. so to debug it I just tried returning the input as such..

Comment: In 2.1 you'll need `udf` with `(Seq[Row]) => Seq[ (String,String,Int)]` as in the linked question. Since 2.4 there are better options available. As of casting - it will work only for identity, because actual types don't match. That's why I decided that the answer is not worth keeping.

Comment: let me try it., 2.4 would be adopted in my project after March-2019.. do you have  an example

Comment: You can start with `df.selectExpr("transform(trans_vec, (x, i) -> (x, i))")`

Comment: that seems to be available in 2.4 it gives some parse exception error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, if the below code is replaced from

```
val df2 = df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list(struct('dt,'amt)).as("trans_vec"))
```

to

```
val df2 = df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list(struct('dt.as("_1"),'amt.as("_2")).as("trans_vec"))
```

Looks like UDFs just assigns _1, _2.. and so on for the Array of Struct passed to it.
Later you can rename them using the select()

Comment: Had, same exact weird problem. Thanks for the solution. I wonder if it's possible to pass the names of the columns in struct to udf somehow then obeying its forced _1, _2 syntax.