# Why do I get "Failed to execute user defined function"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have the following case

```
// using spark 2.2
case class myAttribute(name:String,value:String)
case class person(id:String,attr:List[myAttribute])


val myFunc: (Seq[myAttribute] => Map[String, String]) = { array =>
  array.map {
    case myAttribute(name: String, value: String) =>
      (name, value)
  }.toMap
}
val myUDF = udf(myFunc)
```

on applying `myUDF` as

```
val df = List(person("1",List(myAttribute("s","s"))),person("2",List(myAttribute("b","b")))).toDF()

df.withColumn("tst",myUDF2($"attr")).show
```

I get the following error

```
   org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
 Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1:   (array<struct<name:string,value:string>>) => map<string,string>)

  .......
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be   cast to myAttribute
  at $anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(<pastie>:30)
```

But when I change `myAttribute` to `Row` in the udf, it works fine. But why ? The column `attr` is of type `Seq[myAttribute]`. Am I missing something ?

**EDIT**  I went through [Defining a UDF that accepts an Array of objects in a Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39006349/defining-a-udf-that-accepts-an-array-of-objects-in-a-spark-dataframe), which explains `Row` should be used, which I know. I want to ask, why despite my column being of type `myAttribute` I have to give generic type `Row` instead of `myAttribute` in the UDF ?

Comment: @user6910411 its not a duplicate. I know that Row has to be used. I am asking why wont my case class work.

Comment: Because, as already answered in the linked thread, this is what specification says - `udf` receives types according to schema, external type for `struct` is `Row`. There is nothing more to that.