# Spark udf error task not serializable (scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I work on a scala spark project. I would like to retrieve the wording of a code with 2 dataframes.

I have 2 dataframes :

- one with the column with the code that I would retrieve the wording. (column interest)

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPGpQ.png)

- the second with 2 columns the code and the wording of this code.

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCQ3x.png)

I do this :

```
def CodeToInterest(df: sql.DataFrame, codesList: sql.DataFrame) : sql.DataFrame = {
val spark =  SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val transformList = udf((init: Array[String]) => {
  if(init == null) return null
  else init.map((code: String) => {
    if(!code.startsWith("IAB")) code
    else codesList.filter($"Code" === code)
        .first()
        .getAs[String]("Interest")
  })
}).apply(col("interests"))

df.withColumn("newInterests", transformList)

}
```

But I have this error.

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:403)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1(RDD.scala:850)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex(RDD.scala:849)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:3370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:751)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:719)
    at SassWI.RetrieveData$.main(RetrieveData.scala:46)
    at SassWI.RetrieveData.main(RetrieveData.scala) 
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.Object
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: java.lang.Object, value: java.lang.Object@3aeb267)
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 3)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class SassWI.Etl$, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function1.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic SassWI/Etl$.$anonfun$CodeToInterest$1:(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/Dataset;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession;[Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;, instantiatedMethodType=([Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;, numCaptured=3])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class SassWI.Etl$$$Lambda$2075/1442249061, SassWI.Etl$$$Lambda$2075/1442249061@4b56b517)
    - element of array (index: 5)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 6)
    - element of array (index: 1)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 3)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function2.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic org/apache/spark/sql/execution/WholeStageCodegenExec.$anonfun$doExecute$4$adapted:(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/codegen/CodeAndComment;[Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/metric/SQLMetric;Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/collection/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;, instantiatedMethodType=(Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/collection/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;, numCaptured=3])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$Lambda$1308/216359372, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$Lambda$1308/216359372@3acc3ee)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:400)
    ... 33 more
```

Do you have an idea of what caused this error?
Thanks.

Comment: Does not quite look right.

Comment: try changing to Seq instead of Array
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39006349/defining-a-udf-that-accepts-an-array-of-objects-in-a-spark-dataframe

Comment: There is a problem with your UDF, This error occur when there is variable that we are using in UDF but not passing as  a parameter. I am also seeing variable like codeList that are not declare inside UDF.  I can provide you UDF if you provide dataframe in text here (not image ) and also expected output

Comment: It seems to me that using `first()` inside of the `udf` violates how spark works: the udf is applied row-wise on seperate workers, `first()` sends the first element of a distributed collection back to the driver application. But then you are still in the udf so the value must be serialized. I would recommend to use broadcast to make the code -> wording table available to all workers and use a simple map to transform the codes.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried changing the Array to a Seq, it is not working, @moe How can I replace the first() ?

Comment: @marie_ig I think the problem is that you try to use the `dataframe`s like objects in a 'regular' programming language. you want to map the codes in your data by looking up the meaning of the code in the other dataframe. To achieve this you try to filter the lookup table for the needed code each time you process a row.  But you can not acces a distributed dataset like this. Since the look up table will probably be rather small you should not read it as a dataset but as a regular map in scala. Then you can broadcast it and use it in yout transformation as you intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a solution to this issue. According to the documentation, an array in a Spark dataframe is represented as a mutable.WrappedArray in Scala. That was why the engine couldn't cast this type!

```
    val spark =  SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val codes: Map[String, String] = codesList.as[(String, String)].collect().toMap

    val transformList = udf((init: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => {
      if(init == null) init
      else {
        init.map((code: String) => {
          if(!code.startsWith("IAB")) code.toLowerCase()
          else codes(code).toLowerCase()
        })
      }
    }).apply(col("interests"))

    df.withColumn("newInterests", array_distinct(transformList))
  }
```

Thanks to all who gave some help!